# MYSQL - how to store date and time as UTC rather than EST?

Tags: java, mysql, datetime, timestamp

In my application I have the following 2 columns:

```
start - datetime
end - datetime
```

Corresponding java fields:

```
@JsonProperty
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "start")
private Calendar start;

@JsonProperty
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "end")
private Calendar end;
```

Whenever the front end calls the back end to persist an entity it is always saved as `EST` time.

E.g. if the time is sent as `12pm` it is saved in the DB as `8am.`

How can I ensure that the time saved in the DB is always in `UTC`?

I tried changing the type of the `start` column to be `timestamp`, but this did not solve it.

Comment: [Calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48688736/are-java-util-date-and-java-util-calendar-deprecated)? Really?

Comment: Use `java.time.OffsetDateTime` (or maybe `java.time.ZonedDateTime`) instead of `java.util.Calendar`. Oh, and check the time zone of (1) your system and (2) the database.

Comment: so should I change both calendar >ZonedDatetime in java, and datetime > timestamp in mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TIMESTAMP data types are stored in UTC in MySql. (DATETIME data types are not.)

When you store them they're translated from the connection's, or server's, time zone setting to UTC. And, when you retrieve them they're translated back.

To make this work you need to ensure the time zone setting is correct on each connection.  Something like this will do the trick, if you do it while opening the connection or before handling any TIMESTAMP data.

```
SET time_zone = 'America/Halifax';
```

Global web apps (WordPress for example) have a user preference setting for time zone, so each user can see times in their own local time.

If you want to retrieve UTC times, do this first:

```
SET time_zone = 'UTC';
```