# Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK is returning wrong week?

Tags: android, android-calendar, android-date

Funny thing is that this Calendar is returning first day of the week as next Sunday which is completely illogical.

So I made index conversion function to sort days.
It worked for January, but as soon as I moved to February, out of nowhere, first week of the February is last week of January for some reason.

So days are now fine, but weeks are out of order for some reason. Even `Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK` is returning wrong data for specific `Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH`. There is zero logic in this native `Calendar` and I cant make simple iterator over all days of the year to form some usable structure for my custom Calendar.

Code:

```
private fun loadDatePickerYear(year: Int): DatePickerYear{
    val cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.forLanguageTag("cs"))
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year)
    val months = mutableListOf<DatePickerMonth>()
    (0..11).forEach { month->
        months.add(loadDatePickerMonth(cal, month))
    }
    return DatePickerYear(months, year)
}
private fun loadDatePickerMonth(cal: Calendar, month: Int): DatePickerMonth{
    App.log("DatePickerNew: loadDatePickerMonth: $month")
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month)
    val firstWeek = cal.getActualMinimum(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH)
    val lastWeek = cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH)
    val weeks = mutableListOf<DatePickerWeek>()
    (firstWeek..lastWeek).forEach { week->
        weeks.add(loadDatePickerWeek(cal, week))
    }
    return DatePickerMonth(weeks, month)
}

private fun loadDatePickerWeek(cal: Calendar, week: Int): DatePickerWeek{
    App.log("DatePickerNew: loadDatePickerWeek: $week")
    cal.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH, week)
    val firstDay = cal.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)
    val lastDay = cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)
    val days = mutableListOf<DatePickerDay>()
    (firstDay..lastDay).forEach { day->
        days.add(loadDatePickerDay(cal, day))
    }

    days.sortBy { it.dayOfWeek }
    days.forEach {
        App.log("DatePickerNew: loadDatePickerWeek: sorted: ${it.dayOfWeek}, ${it.dayAsDate}")
    }
    return DatePickerWeek(days, week)
}

private fun loadDatePickerDay(cal: Calendar, day: Int): DatePickerDay{
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, day)
    val date = Date(cal.timeInMillis)
    //return day
    App.log("DatePickerNew: loadDatePickerDay: $day $date")
    return DatePickerDay(date, getEuropeanDayIndex(day)!!)
}

//2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1
fun getEuropeanDayIndex(dayOfWeek: Int): Int?{
    return when(dayOfWeek){
        1 -> 7
        2 -> 1
        3 -> 2
        4 -> 3
        5 -> 4
        6 -> 5
        7 -> 6
        else -> null
    }
}
```

Logs for January (first 2 weeks):

```
DatePickerNew: loadDatePickerMonth: 0
DatePickerNew: loadDatePickerWeek: 0
DatePickerNew: loadDatePickerDay: 1 Sun Jan 02 11:24:01 GMT+01:00 2022
DatePickerNew: loadDatePickerDay: 2 Mon Dec 27 11:24:01 GMT+01:00 2021
DatePickerNew: loadDatePickerDay: 3 Tue Dec 28 11:24:01 GMT+01:00 2021
DatePickerNew: loadDatePickerDay: 4 Wed Dec 29 11:24:01 GMT+01:00 2021
DatePickerNew: loadDatePickerDay: 5 Thu Dec 30 11:24:01 GMT+01:00 2021
DatePickerNew: loadDatePickerDay: 6 Fri Dec 31 11:24:01 GMT+01:00 2021
DatePickerNew: loadDatePickerDay: 7 Sat Jan 01 11:24:01 GMT+01:00 2022
DatePickerNew: loadDatePickerWeek: sorted: 1, Mon Dec 27 11:24:01 GMT+01:00 2021
DatePickerNew: loadDatePickerWeek: sorted: 2, Tue Dec 28 11:24:01 GMT+01:00 2021
DatePickerNew: loadDatePickerWeek: sorted: 3, Wed Dec 29 11:24:01 GMT+01:00 2021
DatePickerNew: loadDatePickerWeek: sorted: 4, Thu Dec 30 11:24:01 GMT+01:00 2021
DatePickerNew: loadDatePickerWeek: sorted: 5, Fri Dec 31 11:24:01 GMT+01:00 2021
DatePickerNew: loadDatePickerWeek: sorted: 6, Sat Jan 01 11:24:01 GMT+01:00 2022
DatePickerNew: loadDatePickerWeek: sorted: 7, Sun Jan 02 11:24:01 GMT+01:00 2022
DatePickerNew: loadDatePickerWeek: 1
DatePickerNew: loadDatePickerDay: 1 Sun Jan 09 11:24:01 GMT+01:00 2022
DatePickerNew: loadDatePickerDay: 2 Mon Jan 03 11:24:01 GMT+01:00 2022
DatePickerNew: loadDatePickerDay: 3 Tue Jan 04 11:24:01 GMT+01:00 2022
DatePickerNew: loadDatePickerDay: 4 Wed Jan 05 11:24:01 GMT+01:00 2022
DatePickerNew: loadDatePickerDay: 5 Thu Jan 06 11:24:01 GMT+01:00 2022
DatePickerNew: loadDatePickerDay: 6 Fri Jan 07 11:24:01 GMT+01:00 2022
DatePickerNew: loadDatePickerDay: 7 Sat Jan 08 11:24:01 GMT+01:00 2022
DatePickerNew: loadDatePickerWeek: sorted: 1, Mon Jan 03 11:24:01 GMT+01:00 2022
DatePickerNew: loadDatePickerWeek: sorted: 2, Tue Jan 04 11:24:01 GMT+01:00 2022
DatePickerNew: loadDatePickerWeek: sorted: 3, Wed Jan 05 11:24:01 GMT+01:00 2022
DatePickerNew: loadDatePickerWeek: sorted: 4, Thu Jan 06 11:24:01 GMT+01:00 2022
DatePickerNew: loadDatePickerWeek: sorted: 5, Fri Jan 07 11:24:01 GMT+01:00 2022
DatePickerNew: loadDatePickerWeek: sorted: 6, Sat Jan 08 11:24:01 GMT+01:00 2022
DatePickerNew: loadDatePickerWeek: sorted: 7, Sun Jan 09 11:24:01 GMT+01:00 2022
```

Logs for February (first 2 weeks):

```
DatePickerNew: loadDatePickerMonth: 1
DatePickerNew: loadDatePickerWeek: 0
DatePickerNew: loadDatePickerDay: 1 Sun Jan 30 11:24:01 GMT+01:00 2022
DatePickerNew: loadDatePickerDay: 2 Mon Jan 24 11:24:01 GMT+01:00 2022
DatePickerNew: loadDatePickerDay: 3 Tue Jan 25 11:24:01 GMT+01:00 2022
DatePickerNew: loadDatePickerDay: 4 Wed Jan 26 11:24:01 GMT+01:00 2022
DatePickerNew: loadDatePickerDay: 5 Thu Jan 27 11:24:01 GMT+01:00 2022
DatePickerNew: loadDatePickerDay: 6 Fri Jan 28 11:24:01 GMT+01:00 2022
DatePickerNew: loadDatePickerDay: 7 Sat Jan 29 11:24:01 GMT+01:00 2022
DatePickerNew: loadDatePickerWeek: sorted: 1, Mon Jan 24 11:24:01 GMT+01:00 2022
DatePickerNew: loadDatePickerWeek: sorted: 2, Tue Jan 25 11:24:01 GMT+01:00 2022
DatePickerNew: loadDatePickerWeek: sorted: 3, Wed Jan 26 11:24:01 GMT+01:00 2022
DatePickerNew: loadDatePickerWeek: sorted: 4, Thu Jan 27 11:24:01 GMT+01:00 2022
DatePickerNew: loadDatePickerWeek: sorted: 5, Fri Jan 28 11:24:01 GMT+01:00 2022
DatePickerNew: loadDatePickerWeek: sorted: 6, Sat Jan 29 11:24:01 GMT+01:00 2022
DatePickerNew: loadDatePickerWeek: sorted: 7, Sun Jan 30 11:24:01 GMT+01:00 2022
DatePickerNew: loadDatePickerWeek: 1
DatePickerNew: loadDatePickerDay: 1 Sun Jan 09 11:24:01 GMT+01:00 2022
DatePickerNew: loadDatePickerDay: 2 Mon Jan 03 11:24:01 GMT+01:00 2022
DatePickerNew: loadDatePickerDay: 3 Tue Jan 04 11:24:01 GMT+01:00 2022
DatePickerNew: loadDatePickerDay: 4 Wed Jan 05 11:24:01 GMT+01:00 2022
DatePickerNew: loadDatePickerDay: 5 Thu Jan 06 11:24:01 GMT+01:00 2022
DatePickerNew: loadDatePickerDay: 6 Fri Jan 07 11:24:01 GMT+01:00 2022
DatePickerNew: loadDatePickerDay: 7 Sat Jan 08 11:24:01 GMT+01:00 2022
DatePickerNew: loadDatePickerWeek: sorted: 1, Mon Jan 03 11:24:01 GMT+01:00 2022
DatePickerNew: loadDatePickerWeek: sorted: 2, Tue Jan 04 11:24:01 GMT+01:00 2022
DatePickerNew: loadDatePickerWeek: sorted: 3, Wed Jan 05 11:24:01 GMT+01:00 2022
DatePickerNew: loadDatePickerWeek: sorted: 4, Thu Jan 06 11:24:01 GMT+01:00 2022
DatePickerNew: loadDatePickerWeek: sorted: 5, Fri Jan 07 11:24:01 GMT+01:00 2022
DatePickerNew: loadDatePickerWeek: sorted: 6, Sat Jan 08 11:24:01 GMT+01:00 2022
DatePickerNew: loadDatePickerWeek: sorted: 7, Sun Jan 09 11:24:01 GMT+01:00 2022
```

Comment: show us your code

Answer (score 0):

```
if you are making custom calendar then make the layout start from "Monday" and 
get week start day as monday like:

Actually you have not shared your customcalender code so this is what i 
get from current question

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,  Calendar.MONDAY- 
calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
Log.w(TAG, "first day of week" + calendar.getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix the week numbers you can maybe do

```
cal.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
```

Right after you create it

Comment: This doesnt work at all. I added it and it still returned Sunday at first index

Comment: @martin1337 I didn't mean it as replacement for your `getEuropeanDayIndex`, you still would need that, but I thought it might fix the week number problem you still had. There's no way to change `Calendar.SUNDAY` to not be 1, that's a constant.

Comment: Yeah, days are working correctly now. Issue is with weeks of month, its complete mess and I cant see any logic behind that behavior.

Comment: I wanna create Calendar recyclerview similar to what Windows 10 have. I need to split months into weeks and weeks into days so I can add it to RecyclerView as rows. But Calendar behavior is weird and I dont understand why.

Comment: @martin1337 you might want to move away from `Calendar` entirely. There are better date time classes. `Calendar` is regarded as old and deprecated by most developers. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48688736/are-java-util-date-and-java-util-calendar-deprecated for example

Comment: I would like to use new classes but my app is supporting minSDK 21, so I cant use LocalDate class because its from Android Oreo+. There are some libraries which are simulating LocalDate, but those are in maintenance mode.