# Trying to use Calendar instance for p:datePicker component

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datepicker

I am working on a PrimeFaces project and since the 10.0 migration the `p:calendar` component in my xhtml is deprecated. I have replaced it with `p:datePicker`, but I don't know if I can still use these line of codes to get the `DatePicker` instance in the bean:

```java
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(startDate);
```

Also, do I have to convert my `Date`s to `LocalDate`?

I have tried to keep these lines of codes that were working with the `p:calendar` component, but it doesn't fire the methods associated in the `p:ajax` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although, technically, if you write a converter, it will be possible to use `Calendar` with `p:datePicker`. However, I would bite the bullet and migrate to the Java 8 date time API instead of converting your `Calendar`s to `Date`. If you are already using `Date`s, you can use them with the `p:datePicker` (although I would still consider converting them to a more modern type).

See also:

- [Are java.util.Date and java.util.Calendar deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48688736/are-java-util-date-and-java-util-calendar-deprecated)

Comment: So from what I understand I could use LocalDateTime instead of Date and I wouldn't need a converter in the xhtml. Thank you for your answer !

Comment: Both `Date` and `LocalDateTime` will work OOTB. `Calendar` won't.

Comment: So using an instance of calendar wouldn't be the best solution, I understand, thank you